# Identity Server v3 as Federation Gateway only

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

Have configured SSO via SAML and WS-Federation in Production using ADFS. New customer is asking to integrate SSO via OpenID Connect (oidc) with Google+.

Identity Server v3 (IdSrv3) supports oidc, so I put together a prototype and I am able to integrate SSO using Google+ as follows:

MyWebApp <-- ws-fed --> ADFS <-- ws-fed --> IdSrv3 <-- oidc --> Google+

Current configuration has IdSrv3 present the user a Login page with option to enter Username and Password and button to use Google+ as IdP.

Can I configure IdSrv3 as a Federation Gateway with Google+ as the only IdP? (i.e. no username password fields)

Please advise,
-Santiago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - set the EnableLocalLogin to false in the AuthenticationOptions

https://github.com/IdentityServer/Thinktecture.IdentityServer3/blob/master/source%2FCore%2FConfiguration%2FAuthenticationOptions.cs#L47