# Identity Server 4 Federation Gateway

Tags: identityserver4, ws-federation

I'm not really seeing a lot of documentation but I have implemented external authentication and external providers. But what's missing for me is:

- How does one configure a client application to point to the federation gateway?
- How do you configure identity server to be federation gateway?
- Does the authentication manager somehow decide what provider to use?

My own research has lead to this:

https://www.identityserver.com/articles/identityserver4-ws-federation-and-sharepoint/
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.WsFederation
[Identity Server v3 as Federation Gateway only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417663/identity-server-v3-as-federation-gateway-only)

Let me know, thanks.

Comment: My apologies. I made the corrections.

Comment: As it is written, your question is far too broad. You are asking three separate questions. Fixing capitalization is nice, but it isn't going to make this a good question.

Comment: I'm not really too sure on how to best ask this. The documentation provides a guidance and highlights a few points but no code samples are given. I have a experience with the identity server 4 and its OAUTH2 flow and I feel these questions are specific.

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.WsFederation - this link is worth its weight in gold. I recommend people take a good look at this project the source code is very good and usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, from my own discoveries and searches for answers, I'm coming to find out that federation gateway is a type of system architecture used to hide and shield how connections are made to external providers. This is true to identity server 4. Identity server can act as a client to these external providers.

if you need to implement that specification with identity server 4, you will need to code your own plug-in to communicate over that protocol. Luckily, Scott Brady (link above) showed us a way to accomplish that. If you're using identity server 3, the team made their own plugin for you to grab from NUGET.

More information later as I get through this. Wish me luck.